# Cut line with line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line

I have 2 lines in 2 layer and I want to make a split where it is crossing each other/intersection point in Qgis 2.16

I want to make one line from the 2 line in the crossing point. I want the new line to be constant. I need the blue line in the pics after splitting. DONT know how to split it in the crossing point...

I have a good picture to see what I really want to do.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to do the following:

1. Use `Split lines with lines` two times. The first time use Line 1 as input and Line 2 as split line, and save the output file (output_1.shp)

[image]

2. The second time use Line 2 as input and Line 1 as split line, and save the output file (output_2.shp)

[image]

3. Use Merge Vector Layers to merge (output 1) and (output 2) together and save the output (Merge.shp)

[image]

4. Load (Merge.shp) into QGIS. Select the the lines that you want, save the selected files into a new shapefile.

[image]